# How to convert this piece of code to Generics?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I have the following extension method that takes a List and converts it to a comma separated string:

```
    static public string ToCsv(this List<string> lst)
    {
        const string SEPARATOR = ", ";
        string csv = string.Empty;

        foreach (var item in lst)
            csv += item + SEPARATOR;

        // remove the trailing separator
        if (csv.Length > 0)
            csv = csv.Remove(csv.Length - SEPARATOR.Length);

        return csv;
    }
```

I want to do something analogous but apply it to a List (instead of List of String) , however, the compiler can't resolve for T:

```
    static public string ToCsv(this List<T> lst)
    {
        const string SEPARATOR = ", ";
        string csv = string.Empty;

        foreach (var item in lst)
            csv += item.ToString() + SEPARATOR;

        // remove the trailing separator
        if (csv.Length > 0)
            csv = csv.Remove(csv.Length - SEPARATOR.Length);

        return csv;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: FWIW, Your CSV code is wrong; you need to put quotes around text in CSV format, in certain cases.

Comment: he didn't say he wanted a "CSV" formated file, just a string from a list of values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the method declaration should be:

```
public static string ToCsv<T>(this List<T> list) { // }
```

Note that the method must be parameterized; this is the `<T>` after the name of the method.

Second, don't reinvent the wheel. Just use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(VS.100).aspx):

```
public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string separator) {
    return String.Join(separator, source.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
}

public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
    return source.ToCsv(", ");
}
```

Note that I've gone hog wild and generalized the method further by accepting an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of a `List<T>`.

In .NET 4.0 you will be able to say:

```
public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string separator) {
    return String.Join(separator, source.Select(x => x.ToString());
}

public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
    return source.ToCsv(", ");
}
```

That is, we do not require to convert the result of `source.Select(x => x.ToString())` to an array.

Finally, for an interesting blog post on this topic, see Eric Lippert's post [Comma Quibbling](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/15/comma-quibbling.aspx).

Comment: my goodness, some of the solutions in the comments are baroque.

Answer (score 7):

Try changing the declaration to

```
static public string ToCsv<T>(this List<T> lst){ ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function needs a generic parameter:

```
static public string ToCsv<T>(this List<T> lst)
                          ^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make this more generic and use IEnumerable instead of a List< T >, after all you are not using any list-specific methods

```
public static string ToCsv<T>(this IEnumerable lst);
```